# How to get space in the answer? (Caesar encrypt)

Tags: encryption

Got a small problem, I'm trying to get this function working.
It is a standard Caesar encipher/encrypt function.

I got it kind of working, but it only returns the whole text (without spaces).
Not the text with spaces, as I would like to have.

My code:

```
def encipher(s, n):

    result = "" 

    for i in range(len(s)): 
        char = s[i] 

        if (char.isupper()): 
            result += chr((ord(char) + n - 65) % 26 + 65) 

        else: 
            result += chr((ord(char) + n - 97) % 26 + 97) 

    return result
```

What i get for the results is:

```
encipher("Z A", 1) == "AoB"
```

Where it has to be

```
encipher("Z A", 1) == "A B"
```

I haven't really tried a fix yet, because idk where to look

Comment: Which programming language do you use? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I'm using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, you want to just skip spaces?  Just add another clause to your if/else statement.

```
def encipher(s, n):

    result = "" 

    for i in range(len(s)): 
        char = s[i] 

        if (char == ' '):
            result +=  ' '

        elif (char.isupper()): 
            result += chr((ord(char) + n - 65) % 26 + 65) 

        else: 
            result += chr((ord(char) + n - 97) % 26 + 97) 

    return result
```

A simpler approach might be to do this:

```
        if (char.isupper()): 
            result += chr((ord(char) + n - 65) % 26 + 65) 

        elif (char.islower()): 
            result += chr((ord(char) + n - 97) % 26 + 97) 

        else:
            result += char
```